# My post content (paragraph) is not show proper way in my frontend website

Tags: wordpress

When i make a post in my website then it's paragraph(text editor content) is not show proper way in front end website(wordpress) .
but content is show in text editor in proper way.

Please give me a solution!
A lots of thanks..[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urLjQ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdunS.png)

Answer (score 0):

Talk to your HTML CSS developers about that..I dont think there is any technical issues. Your paragraph tag must be made to display:none as far as my knowledge is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your theme doesn't support RTL, you can ask the theme developer about this problem or apply the CSS yourself.

- https://codex.wordpress.org/Right_to_Left_Language_Support
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1qxuBsQd74I